# How to detect if user navigates away from my app in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to develop an app which helps people focus. Essentially, users start a session in which they would like to focus. This session lasts as long as the user does not open another app (for example, the user cannot open Facebook). If the user does so, the session is marked as a failure. Users try to last as long as possible.

The issue I see is that iOS does not allow apps to run for more than 3 minutes once the screen turns off. That means that a user can start a session, then put the phone down for 3 or more minutes, and when they unlock the phone, they are presented with their home screen. The app has been killed. A user is then free to roam around and look at any other app, defeating the purpose of my app.

I could use a timer running on a server to maintain overall session duration, and resume the session once the user reopens the app, but this does not solve the issue of users being able to roam before reopening the app.

Are there any ways to get around iOS killing my app? The behavior I want is:
1) User starts session.
2) Session timer begins.
3) If user navigates away from app, session terminates after 30 second warning.
4) If user locks phone, app still runs.
5) When user unlocks phone, app is displayed (not homescreen). Thus, the termination logic is the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an observer (add it to your ViewController's viewDidLoad):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillResignActive(notification:)), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

And the function will look like this:

```
@objc func applicationWillResignActive(notification: NSNotification) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Would you be able to explain what the observer and function are doing? I'm not quite understanding. Will it prevent my app from being suspended or going inactive? The issue I have is when a user locks their phone, and 3 minutes passes, when they come back into the phone my app is in the background now and they are looking at their homescreen. I would like them to always return to the app when the unlock the phone, regardless of time. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. An observer detects an event and notifies you by calling a function when that event happens. In this case, the observer detects when the app is about to go to the background and when that happens it calls the function applicationWillResignActive(). From there you can handle what you want to do when your app goes to the background. Does that make sense?